# Cannot run 'kong migrations bootstrap' ( Ident authentication failed for user "kong")

Tags: postgresql, centos, kong

I'm learning to use Kong. I install it on centos 7. I follow the tutorial from https://docs.konghq.com/install/centos/ I stuck on

> kong migrations bootstrap [-c /path/to/kong.conf]

I've already install Postgres on Centos by following this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-7

I've also created kong Database and User already

[image]

[image]

And already execute this command to setup password for **kong** user

```
ALTER USER kong WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

Here is my kong.conf

```
pg_host = 127.0.0.1
pg_port = 5432
pg_timeout = 5000
pg_user = kong
pg_password = password
pg_database = kong
```

When I execute command **kong migrations bootstrap -c kong.conf** I will get this error

> Error: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve PostgreSQL server_version_num: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "kong"

I'm wasting my time about 3-4 hours on this. I really need help.

**Edit this is my pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Ps. I've found it somewhere recommended to change it as above from

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             ::1/128                ident
```

Comment: Please add the contents of your `pg_hba.conf` to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added it. thx.

Comment: It is not clear which is your current `pg_hba.conf` file, the one with `md5` or the one with `ident`?

Comment: The below content is the original. The above is my current content

Comment: Did you reload/restart the Postgres server after making the change?

Comment: Already did it @AdrianKlaver

Answer (score 1):

for IPv4 local connections:

```
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
```

I made this at its' working !

Comment: Good, though I will point out that this means there is no authentication taking place. It is `localhost` so that limits the potential damage. I would still figure out why `password` was not working. At least temporarily change the `auth` back to md5. Then to troubleshoot I would use `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U kong -d kong` and tail the Postgres log to see what it says.